# Redis Json Module not opening

Tags: json, redis, wsl-2, redisjson

Module rejson.so failed to load: rejson.so: cannot open shared object file

Modified the permissions to write and execute but not working and also put to the etc/redis folder

Comment: Can you please add the full command line you use? and the full error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I use the Node cache module for caching data instead of Redis. Thanks for the Responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the Node cache module for caching data instead of Redis. Thanks for the Responses